# Broken Phone - Google Authenticator inaccessible - Switch Internal Storage To New Phone

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, google-authenticator

I have a Snapped phone. (Huawei p8 Lite ALE L02) That has very important google authenticator codes on it.
The only way I seem them as being salvageable is to replace the internal storage from this device onto another device of the same model.

How and where Do I do this. Willing to do anything.

No I don't have backup keys, I'm an idiot

Comment: Did you 1. Update authenticator app 2. do backup to Google drive? If so , see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190311/131553)

Comment: Google codes, or third party apps using Google Authentication? If the latter, sorry you're out of luck. Moving the internal storage to another device is not economical, it would cost several times the price of a new phone, unless you work for or know someone who can do micro electronics repair.