# Move all my Authenticator credentials to a new phone

Tags: security, google, data-transfer, google-authenticator

I have enabled 2 factor authentication, using Google Authenticator, for 6 services: LastPass, Dropbox, Evernote, Wordpress, Tumblr and Google. How can I transfer them all to my new phone?

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/move-google-authenticator-from-one-android-device-to-another/), but the result of that was only that my Google account authentication was moved to the new phone. So, now I can access one account using my new phone, and need my old one for the other 5.

Surely there is a way to do this in bulk? I don't really need to do something special with each service provider do I?

New phone is Motorola Moto G3, old is Moto G. Both working. Neither rooted.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions available here: [How do I back up Google Authenticator?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63252)

Comment: Some look promising, but they all require rooting. Hmm.

Comment: And since rooting apparently wipes everything, I would have to: 1) Backup, 2) Root 3) Restore 4) Install Authenticator Plus 5) Import from Authenticator 6) Sync to new phone... bleh.

Comment: Rooting doesn't wipe anything, but unlocking your bootloader does.

Comment: What a mistake I made by using Google Authenticator on dozens of sites...

Answer (score 0):

You should disable and re-enable two-factor authentication for each account. In the process of disabling you will be asked to enter the OTP from your old phone. As soon as you disable it you should enable it and add tokens to the Google Authenticator on your new phone.

Comment: The OP was looking for a way to move them all automatically, not manually for each service.